# C++: Operator << in derived class with default parameter?

Tags: c++, stream, operator-overloading

There is a class A having the virtual method print() and overloaded operator << defined as a friend function.

```
#include <iostream>
class A
{
public:
    double a1, a2;
    A(): a1(10.0), a2(10.0) {}

    virtual void print ( std::ostream * o = &std::cout ) const
    {
        *o << a1<< '\t' << a2 << '\n';
        }

    friend std::ostream & operator << ( std::ostream & o, const A &aa )
    {
        o << aa.a1 << '\t' << aa.a2 << '\n';
        return o;
    }
};
```

and analogously in derived class B

```
 class B : public A
 {
public:
    double b1, b2;
    B(): A(), b1(20.0), b2(20.0) {}

    virtual void print ( std::ostream * o = &std::cout ) const
    {
        A::print ( o );
        *o << b1<< '\t' << b2;
    }

    friend std::ostream & operator << ( std::ostream & o, const B &bb )
    {
        o << (A)(bb);
        o << bb.b1 << '\t' << bb.b2 << '\n';
        return o;
    }
 };
```

I have the following questions:

1] Is there any way how to pass a pointer to ostream object with default parameter so as operator << correctly replaces the print() method? This overloading is wrong

```
friend std::ostream & operator << ( std::ostream * o= &std::cout, const A &aa )
```

2] I am not sure, if this line calling operator of the parent class A in derived class B is correct?

```
 o << (A)(bb);
```

3] Is there any better way how to overload operator << without "friend" declaration?

Thanks for your help....

Comment: Why would you replicate the functionality of `print` in `operator<<` when `operator<<` can simply call `print`? And then you only need one `operator<<(ostream&, const Base&)` and it will work for the complete hierarchy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this without friendship:

```
#include <iostream>
class A
{
    double a1, a2;

public:
    A(): a1(10.0), a2(10.0) {}

    virtual void print ( std::ostream * o = &std::cout ) const
    {
        *o << a1 << '\t' << a2;
    }
};

std::ostream & operator << ( std::ostream & o, const A &aa )
{
    o << "( )";
    aa.print(&o);
    return o << " )";
}
```

and then `class B` doesn't a separate version of `operator<<`, this one will be found, and call `B::print` when you pass it a `B` instance.

Comment: For consistency, I would also suggest that print uses a reference rather than a pointer. This would also allow you to avoid the extra operators needed to deal with pointers.

Comment: @Code-Guru: I kept it compatible with the signature used in the question, since there was no compelling reason to change it.

Comment: Good point. For what it's worth, my comment was more for the OP than for you as the answerer. I probably should have added an @ tag for him.

Answer (score 1):

I have long wondered on how to avoid the verbose friend declarations and come up with the following:

```
template<typename T>
class OutEnabled {
  public:
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, T const& val) {
      return static_cast<OutEnabled<T> const&>(val).ioprint(out);
    }

    friend QTextStream& operator<<(QTextStream& out, T const& val) {
      return static_cast<OutEnabled<T> const&>(val).ioprint(out);
    }

    friend QDebug operator<<(QDebug dbg,T const& val) {
      std::stringstream myStream;
      myStream << val;
      dbg.maybeSpace() << myStream.str().c_str();
      return dbg;
    }

  protected:
    template<typename U>
    U& ioprint(U& out) const {
      return static_cast<T const*>(this)->print(out);
    }
};

class Foo:public OutEnabled<Foo>{
  public:
    Foo(){}

    template<typename V>
    V& print(V& out) const{return out<< "Bar";}
};
```

Writing this I can write:

```
std::cout << Foo();
qDebug() << Foo();
```

...

I use this concept a lot since it allows you to specify one print and use it for different streams. I have to use at least the three I mentioned, so for me it is worth the complexity. The friends are out of your class so less typing and it is clear from inheritance that your class is printable. The slight disadvantage is that you have a template in every class that uses OutEnabled.